# java android feching strings from strings.xml

Tags: java, android, xml, string

How do I get strings from strings.xml?

Things I have tried

1. `getString(R.string.id);`
2. `context.getString(R.string.id);` with subclass
3. `getResources().getString(R.string.id);`

and nothing works.

Comment: are you doing it from activity aware class ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The last one should work as long as you are in a class extending activity

Answer (score 0):

The class from which you're trying to do this needs to either extend Activity (or Application) or be passed the Activity/Application context, in order to have visibility of these methods. What you're doing is, otherwise, correct.